# Не нахожу я что-то девчонок(,) красивых как Лизавета

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Не нахожу я что-то девчонок(,) красивых как Лизавета.

> Я ещё не видел кота(,) по-настоящему дружелюбного.

> В России не было людей(,) больных чумой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Правильно:**

Обособление оборота после определяемого слова, **два ударения.**

*Не нахожу я что-то **девчОнок**, красивых как ЛизавЕта.*

*Я ещё не видел **котА**, по-настоящему дружелЮбного.*

*В России не было **людЕй**, больных чумОй.*

**Сравнить:**

Оборот не обособляется при тесной связи со сказуемым. **Одно ударение** (только на обороте).

*Не нахожу я что-то девчонок / более **красИвых**, // чем ЛизавЕта.*

*Я ещё не видел кота / по-настоящему **дружелЮбного**, // и этот  кот тоже не образЕц.*

*В России не было людей / **больных чумОй**, но других болезней было достАточно.*